# Sync Oracle Database with SQL Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, azure, synchronization

I would want to sync up on-premises Oracle database with SQL Azure. Currently I have a DTS package setup for my on-premises applications (both Oracle and SQL Server being on-premise). If I move the SQL Server to Azure, how should this process be designed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to options for moving to Azure:

1. Move to Azure SQL Database
2. Provision a SQL Server VM in Azure

the latter will have the same feature set as your regular on-premise SQL Server. The former is not fully-feature equivalent to SQL Server. Azure SQL Database is just the Database engine part, no SSIS, SSAS, Replication and even TSQL is not fully equivalent to SQL Server.

If you use the VM approach, its safe to assume you can still run your existing packages. However, you need to consider latency between Azure in the cloud and your on-premise Oracle database.

you may also build a custom solution to sync the databases or even use Sync Framework. see: [Database Sync: Oracle and SQL Compact 2-Tier](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-Sync-Oracle-and-037fb083) , just replace the SQL Compact with the SqlSyncProvider which works with the Azure SQL Database. You can change the sample to use an n-tier approach if you want to use WCF as well.

Comment: I like the Sync Framework option better. It should give me more flexibility and reliability as against provisioning a SQL Server on a VM. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

There are few [differences between SQL Server and Azure SQL Database](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/996.compare-sql-server-with-windows-azure-sql-database-en-us.aspx) (SQL Azure renamed) so I suppose your code can work on Azure too with little effort. Azure SQL Databases do not have the same features and AFAIK the DTS package cannot run in the Azure environment. But I suppose you can think, if logic/traffic/latency permits, of running the DTS on premises interacting with the Azure SQL Database and Oracle.
You may find [SQL Data Sync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh456371.aspx) interesting:

> SQL Data Sync is a web service that you use to keep your data synchronized across multiple servers in different locations

Comment: SQL Data Sync works only with SQL Azure and SQL Server/Express/LocalDb databases

Comment: Yes, DTS isnt supported in Azure SQL DB yet and also SQL Data Sync doesnt work for Oracle. I am not sure if Azure Connect can be leveraged here in any way.