# Near real-time ETL of Oracle data to Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have an Oracle DB with data that I need to load and transform into an Azure SQL Database. I have no control over either the DB nor the application that updates its data.

I'm looking at Azure Data Factory, but I really need data changes in Oracle to be reflected as near to real-time as possible.

I would appreciate any suggestions / insights.

Is ADF the correct tool for the job? If so, what is a good approach to use? If not suitable, what should I consider using instead?

Comment: You won't be able to achieve that without changing the application / Oracle DB. With ADF you can schedule a query to run and get new data, but you'll need to do it to each table you have. A smart idea would be changing the application to insert in Oracle and also in a queue that would trigger your ETL

Comment: For real-time you don't really want an ELT/ETL tool like ADF.  Consider a replicaton agent like Attunity or (gulp at the licensing costs) GoldenGate.

Comment: @wBob Thanks for the product name, it looks great! Would you like to add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real-time you don't really want an ELT/ETL tool like ADF. Consider a replication agent like [Attunity](https://www.qlik.com/us/products/attunity-replicate) or (gulp at the licensing costs) [GoldenGate](https://www.oracle.com/uk/middleware/technologies/goldengate.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Data Factory is not good for you. Yes you can copy data from Oracle to Azure SQL database with it. But like @Thiago Custodio said, we need need to do it to each table you have. That's too complicated.

Just reference: [Copy data from and to Oracle by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle).

As you said, you really need data changes in Oracle to be reflected as near to real-time as possible.

The migration/copy time must be very short. Then the data in Oracle and Azure SQL database could be same before the Oracle data changed next time. I searched a lot and didn't find any real-time copy tools. Actually, I think you want the copy could be  something like 'data sync'.

I found this link [Sync Oracle Database with SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384554/sync-oracle-database-with-sql-azure), hope it could give some good ideas for you.

About the data migration or copy, You can using bellow ways:

1. [SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle (OracleToSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-oracle-oracletosql?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. [Azure Database Migration Service (DMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/dms-overview)

Reference tutorial:

1. [Migrating Oracle Databases to SQL Server (OracleToSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/migrating-oracle-databases-to-sql-server-oracletosql?view=sql-server-ver15): SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for Oracle is a comprehensive environment that helps you quickly migrate Oracle databases to Azure SQL database.
2. [How to migrate Oracle to Azure SQL Database with minimum downtime](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/how-to-migrate-oracle-to-sqldb-online/):

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, we went with a product named QLik Replicate (aka Attunity) and it is working very well!

Comment: Great to hear, curious to know on pricing part? I understand it depends on the volume/objects etc?

Comment: @Idleguys Sorry, I don't know. I didn't deal with the payments side.